# Trouble Turning on Wireless Capability

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, keyboard, toshiba-laptop

Windows 7, Toshiba Satellite C655

I got a blue screen a week ago and when I turned my laptop back on my wireless capability was turned OFF. I tried everything from Mobilty Center to troubleshooting to uninstalling and reinstalling my wireless LAN and I'm pretty sure the way to turn it back ON is to press the wireless network button on my laptop <kbd>F8</kbd>.

The problem is, my laptop keyboard is practically broken, so none of the buttons work. My USB keyboard doesn't work because the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys have different functions and the on-screen keyboard doesn't work because it uses the default functions, not computer specific ones.

I have looked practically everywhere but couldn't find a solution.

Is there another way to turn it ON ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/455171/how-can-i-turn-on-wireless-capability-in-windows-7?rq=1

Comment: Did you install the driver for F8 button to work as a on/off switch for WLAN? If you didn't here is the link to it: http://support.toshiba.com/support/modelHome?freeText=2681454

Answer (score 0):

If it was a heat sensor button for your wireless connection you can try putting a cell phone or magnet above the key and seeing if it triggers the switch. The problem is it is a hardwired switch so it is not something you can bypass inside of your operating system. Your alternative option is to obtain an external wireless or wired internet device and use it as a work around.

Answer (score 0):

Purchase a cheap USB Wifi adapter and use that instead - then buy a new keyboard for your laptop.